# Interpretación de estos datos

Tags: r, rstudio

Alguien sabe como interpretar estos datos en del paquete UsingR (babyroom), más que todo en la columna "Clock.Time" y "running.time".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¡Hola Santiago!

En R cuando utilizas unos datos de un paquete, si quieres tener más información, basta que realices lo siguiente:

```
# Obtener información sobre "babyboom"
  ?babyboom
```

Este comando te abrirá una ventana "Help" en la que te aparece la siguiente información en la categoría de **Format**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por tanto, "clock.time" hace referencia a la hora de reloj cuando nació el bebé, mientras que "running.time" a los minutos que pasaron desde la media noche del nacimiento.

Saludos,